# How do I access Stock Item images using the acumatica web services?

Tags: upload, erp, acumatica

How do I access Stock Item images using the web services?  It seems like Acumatica only returns the first image, but not the entire array?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, using Stock items screen you will get only first image from array.
So in this case i would like to suggest to use screen SM202520 - Organization-Communication-Search in Files. You can choose a screen and after filter files.